# How do I load system.data configuration section when my entry point is a DLL and the hosting application is not .NET

Tags: sqlite, com, c#-2.0, configurationsection, dbproviderfactories

I am working on a .NET DLL that is interacted with via COM in a number of different applications written in Java, Visual Basic 6 and c++.

The application is using SQLite for client databases and we are using the system.data DbProviderFactory configuration section to provide the information to the DLL about where to get the connections.  This works fine if the hosting application is in .NET but how do I load that section through code if the application is not a .NET application?

We've tried loading it from a specifically named config file using a ConfigurationFileMap and the ConfigurationManager, but this section specifically doesn't load and only contains the entries from machine.config.

Is there any explicit way of loading this section from a named configuration file?